# How to debug AJAX (POST) with PhpStorm and Xdebug?

Tags: ajax, post, phpstorm, xdebug

I have configured PhpStorm to debug HTTP GET - but only when I load a page directly.

When I want to debug AJAX, I take the URL which my JS would request and create a PhpStorm configuration to debug it.

Not particularly elegant, is it?

And, of course, I can't do that for POST requests (or can I?).

Ideally, I would like to load my AngularJs app in the browser (Chrome) and be able to breakpoint and debug the backend in PhpStorm.

I googled a lot, and found much that came close, but I can't find the answer :-(

Who can help?

---

[Update] a few years later, and I am using the excellent and free [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test both GET and POST.

Comment: I see no probs at all -- activate "phone handle" icon in PhpStorm so that it is listening for incoming debug requests; using some xdebug browser extension (or any other supported way,e.g. manually) set xdebug cookie ... and next request processed by PHP should be catched by xdebug. This is, of course, requires correct xdebug setup - as long as you can debug ordinary PHP pages this way it should work just fine. You may also need to increase number of simultaneous debug con-s in PhpStorm settings -- this will allow you to debug few parallel requests (if there will be such need) or sub-requests.

Comment: You can also set `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in your php.ini so that xdebug will initiated debug session for *every single request*.

Comment: AJAX call doesn't break with this setup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If Xdebug and PHPStorm are configured to debug HTTP GET when loading a page normally, then simply include the GET parameter in the URL of the AJAX request in your Javascript. For example: `http://example.com/script.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM`

Turn on Debug listening in PHPStorm, send the AJAX request with the new URL, and the debugger should catch it. The POST data you are looking for should appear in $_POST as usual.

Comment: Lets say URL = /v1/abc.  So it is calling API which will map /v1/abc. Most likely v1 class with abc method.  What is the new URL if I want to PHPStorm to break at abc method?

Comment: Amazing and so simple, I was searching for almost an hour how I can debug a fetch post  request from my Chrome extension

Answer (score 2):

I am using kind of hacking method to debug AJAX requests. My project is Laravel. You can change this code as compatible with your technology.

Basic idea is:

1. Grab home page debug port
2. Create a session
3. Using this session concatenate the AJAX url

When you start debugging, the port will be applied for all ajax urls which having `+ debug_url`.

**HomeController@index method**

```
// Development purpose only
if ($request->has('XDEBUG_SESSION_START')) $request->session()->put('debug_port' , $request->get('XDEBUG_SESSION_START'));
```

**master.blade.php**

```
<script>
  var debug_url='?XDEBUG_SESSION_START={{session('debug_port')}}';
</script>
```

**submit.blade.php**

```
<script>
  $.ajax(url + debug_url, {
     method:'post',
     data:{}
  });
</script>
```